# get_result()->fetch_assoc() always returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this php code :

```
public function getcabang(){

    $cabang = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT nama_cabang,alamat FROM cabang");

    if ($cabang->execute()){
        $cbg = $cabang->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $cabang->close();
        return $cbg;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

but it always returning 1 row :

```
{"error":false,"cabang":{"nama_cabang":"Senayan","alamat":"Pintu 1 Senayan"}}
```

even though it have more than 1 row in table

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` only returns one row at a time. You need to iterate over the result set to get all the rows.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate to get every row, here is an example from [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) :

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

In your case, that would be :

```
public function getcabang(){

    $cabang = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT nama_cabang,alamat FROM cabang");

    if ($cabang->execute()){
        $cbg = array();
        $result = $cabang->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cbg[] = $row;
        }
        $cabang->close();
        return $cbg;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    } 
}
```

Also, a better solution could be to use [mysqli_fetch_all](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) (Available only with mysqlnd)